# "There is no much xxx" vs "There is not much xxx"

Tags: word-choice, differences

"There is ***no*** much xxx" vs "There is ***not*** much xxx"

if 'much' has to be in place, is the first one "no much" wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"no much" is grammatically incorrect